# Setting up 'Trigger Email' Firebase Extension

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I learned about firebase and cloud functions recently and have been able to develop simple applications with them.

I now want to expand my knowledge and really struggling with Trigger Email Extension.

On a specific event on my firebase, I want to fire an email to the user in a custom format, but I am unable to even activate the extension for now.
Can someone please explain **with example please** about these fields marked in the picture?

[image: attach]

Answer (score 1):

I had this question too, but got it resolved. Here's your answer:

"Email documents collection" is the collection that will be read to trigger the emails. I recommend leaving named "mail" unless you already have a collection named mail.

"Users collection (Optional)" refers to a collection (if any) that you want to use in tandem with a user auth system. I haven't had this specific use case yet, but I imagine once you understand how Trigger Email operates, it should be somewhat self-explanatory.

"Templates collection (Optional)" is helpful for templates in which you can use handlebar.js is automatically input specific information per user. (eg. `<p>Hello, {{first_name}}</p>` etc.) Similar to the previously mentioned collections, you can name it whatever you want.

How to create a template (I have yet to actually implement this, so take this with a grain of salt):
In your templates collection, you want to name each document with a memorable ID. Firebase gives the example:

```
{
  subject: "@{{username}} is now following you!",
  html: "Just writing to let you know that <code>@{{username}}</code> ({{name}}) is now following you.",
  attachments: [
    {
     filename: "{{username}}.jpg",
     path: "{{imagePath}}" 
    }
  ]
}
```

...specifying a good ID would be `following`. As you can see, the documents should be structured just like any other email you would send out.

Here is an example of using the above template in javascript:

```
firestore()
  .collection("mail")
    .add({
      toUids: ["abc123"], // This relates to the Users Collection
      template: {
        name: "following", // Specify the template
        // Specify the information for the Handlebars
        // which can also be pulled from your users (toUids)
        // if you have the data stored in a user collection.
        // Of course that gets more into the world of a user auth system.
        data: {
          username: "ada",
          name: "Ada Lovelace",
          imagePath: "https://path-to-file/image-name.jpg"
        },
      },
    })
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have an issues getting this set up.